# What is function of 的 in 挺.......的?

Tags: grammar, particles

I am understanding 挺。。。的 to mean "quite"

I don't get the sense that the 的 is nominalizing an elided phrase particularly, or is this wrong? If yes/no, how/why?

Additionally, why/when is it appropriate to sometimes not use the 的?

Answer (score 1):

挺... is the brief/short version of 挺....的, both mean "quite".

挺好的 = 挺好

他們長的挺相似的 = 他們長的挺相似

她過得挺自在的 = 她過得挺自在

However, assertiveness sometimes leaves the listener with a negative impression about the speaker - "impatient", "not so friendly", or even "rude".

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker, I'd like to say it's a phenomenon but there's no grammatical reason for it. As @r13 said, with or without "的" both make sense. Whether add it or not is really random. Sometimes people are just too lazy to add one in oral.

Comment: So presumably, when writing, you definitely add it, but when speaking it is dropped in casual situations?

Comment: @Nmdy In fact the usge of "挺" as an adjective is quite casual, and I think it only exists in spoken language. Even if it exists in written text, I can only imagine it will imitate a spoken/casual mood.

Comment: By the way, there is a similar casual word of saying "quite": "蛮(man2)...的".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to dwell so much, as a Chinese, with no "的" to see the mood of the speaker, this is just a tone aid. The only difference is that grammatically, with "的" is an adjective, without "的" is a noun, nothing more.